# If $a = \operatorname{cis}A, b = \operatorname{cis}B, c=\operatorname{cis}C\text{, }$ and a + b + c = 0, prove that 1/a + 1/b + 1/c = 0

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

***If***:      $a$ $=$ $e^{i\alpha}$, $b$ $=$ $e^{i\beta},$ $c$ $=$ $e^{i\gamma}$ and $a + b + c = 0$, **prove** that $a^{-1} + b^{-1} +c^{-1} = 0$

Comment: Question related to properties of conjugates and moduli of complex numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $a+b+c=0\;,$ Then taking Conjugate on both side, We get

$$\bar{a}+\bar{b}+\bar{c} = 0\Rightarrow e^{-i \alpha}+e^{-i\beta}+e^{-i\gamma} = 0$$

Where ${a} = e^{i\alpha}\;,$Then replace $i\rightarrow -i\;,$ We get $\bar{a}=e^{-i\alpha}$

So $$\frac{1}{e^{i\alpha}}+\frac{1}{e^{i\beta}}+\frac{1}{e^{i\gamma}} =0$$

So $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} = 0$$